# Add constraint to ManyToMany table on Django model

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I have next models (I left only columns which are connected to the question):

```
class Student(models.Model):
    student_examin = models.ManyToMany("Examin",
        verbose_name=u"Examin",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        through="ExaminResult")
    student_group = models.ForeignKey("Group",
        verbose_name=u"Група",
        blank=False,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Examin(models.Model):
    examin_group = models.OneToOne("Group",
        verbose_name=u"Група",
        blank=False,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ExaminResult(models.Model):
        student = models.ForeignKey("Student",
            verbose_name=u"Студент",
            blank=False,
            null=False,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        examin = models.ForeignKey("Examin",
            verbose_name=u"Екзамін",
            blank=False,
            null=False,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So I have **Student** model who has a **Group** and many **Examin**s. I have an **Examin** model for specific **Group**. And I have connection table **ExaminResult** which connects students with their examins (later on I will add here grades column). My question is how to add constraint to table ExaminResult so that student was added to examin for the same group (so that student and examin in this table have the reference to the same Group model). So to prevent situation when student is added to examin for different group.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no direct way to enforce that at the database level from the ORM. What you can do, is do the [validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) yourself:

```
class ExaminResult(models.Model):
    # ....
    def clean(self):
         if self.student.student_group != self.examin.examin_group:
            # this will appear in form.errors if saved through a ModelForm
            raise ValidationError('Group mismatch betwenn examin and student!')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # make sure any saving triggers validation
        self.clean()
        super(ExaminResult, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This does not prevent illegal states if e.g. you change a student's group after they already have a result.

Comment: I don't think this works for typical operations like `student.student_examin__set.add(result)` because the `ManyRelatedManager` seems to use `bulk_create` which doesn't call `save`: https://github.com/django/django/blob/d2b688b966f5d30414899549412d370e1317ddb8/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L1386